# Custom animation for tableView.moveRow(at: to:)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I have a UITableView with three sections set up which works as expected.

When a button is tapped, multiple cells at a time will move either between section 0 and 1, or 1 and 2. This all works fine, however the default animation is too fast for my needs. Is it possible to define a custom animation or remove the default animation entirely for...

```
tableView.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), to: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1))
```

I have tried using `tableView.insertRows` and `tableView.deleteRows` with their animations set to `.none` as an alternative, but even then there is still a default animation happening where the rows collapse on top of each other and vanish.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

#### Implement Custom Methods with Custom Animation

The default animations in iOS are triggered using a combination of a delegate method and enumeration values.  The animation is baked into the UITableView component.  To implement your own custom animation, you would need to define your own methods to handle CRUD operations and override the drawRect method to carefully implement your animation, according to your timing needs.  You would also need to handle your own deletion and data source sync, of course.

#### Consider the Following

On a philosophical note, by deviating from the standard timing, you will be walking away from the standardized iOS experience for this action.  By doing so, your user may gain the sense that your application is less performant.